# React useContext + TypeScript scoping error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Trying to work with `context`/`hooks` and `TypeScript` for the first time.  Because I'm sending a value *and* a function (dispatch / setter function), I'm using the `Provider` separation pattern outlined in [this blog post, under the header "Pattern B - A Separation"](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-context-patterns-with-usecontext-hook-62085b90c7eb#d378).

The following setup works as expected as long as I export my `StateContext` and `DispatchContext` objects and import them for use with `useContext` in the consuming component.

```
    // src/components/index.tsx
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
        <MyProvider>
          <MyComponent />
        </MyProvider>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

```
    // src/providers/myProvider.tsx
    import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

    type MyProviderProps = { children: React.ReactNode };
    type State = string | undefined;
    type Dispatch = (value: State) => void;

    export const StateContext = React.createContext<State>(undefined);
    export const DispatchContext = React.createContext<Dispatch | undefined>(undefined);

    export function MyProvider({ children }: MyProviderProps) {
      const [state, dispatch] = useState<State>(undefined);

      return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
          <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            {children}
          </DispatchContext.Provider>
        </StateContext.Provider>
      );
    }
```

```
    // src/components/MyComponent.tsx
    import React from "react";
    import {
      StateContext,
      DispatchContext,
    } from "../providers/myProvider";

    export default function MyComponent() {
      const myMessage = React.useContext(StateContext);
      const setMyMessage = React.useContext(DispatchContext);


      return (
        <div>{myMessage}</div>
      );
    }
```

*However*, if I try to create helper functions for `useContext(XyzContext)`, I get an error because the context is `undefined`: `useMyMessage must be used within MyProvider`.  I can't figure out why this helper function causes an issue.

```
    // src/providers/myProvider.tsx
    import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

    type MyProviderProps = { children: React.ReactNode };
    type State = string | undefined;
    type Dispatch = (value: State) => void;

    const StateContext = React.createContext<State>(undefined);
    const DispatchContext = React.createContext<Dispatch | undefined>(undefined);

    export function MyProvider({ children }: MyProviderProps) {
      const [state, dispatch] = useState<State>(undefined);

      return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
          <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            {children}
          </DispatchContext.Provider>
        </StateContext.Provider>
      );
    }

    export function useMyMessage() {
      const context = useContext(StateContext);
      if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useMyMessage must be used within MyProvider");
      }
      return context;
    }
```

```
    // src/components/MyComponent.tsx
    import React from "react";
    import {
      useMyMessage,
      DispatchContext,
    } from "../providers/myProvider";

    export default function MyComponent() {
      const myMessage = useMyMessage();
      const setMyMessage = React.useContext(DispatchContext);


      return (
        <div>{myMessage}</div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Is MyComponent rendered within `MyProvider`?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Updated my question to show the component tree.  It is rendered within the component (it works as expected when I export the `Context`s, but complains when I use the helper methods).